# How to make a loop to print the following pattern?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I want to write a program that prints out the following pattern by using loop. Right now I am able to print it by using only `system.out.println`. I have no idea which loop I should make.

The pattern will be:

```
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * *
* * * * *
```

My code:

```
  package pettern;

public class Pettern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initializing
        String tenStar = "* * * * * * * * * *";
        String NineStar = "* * * * * * * * *";
        String EightStar = "* * * * * * * *";
        String SevenStar = "* * * * * * *";
        String SixStar = "* * * * * *";
        String FiveStar = "* * * * *";

        //printing them out
        System.out.println(tenStar);
        System.out.println(NineStar);
        System.out.println(EightStar);
        System.out.println(SevenStar);
        System.out.println(SixStar);
        System.out.println(FiveStar);

    }

}
```

Comment: Try a for loop, counting from 10 down to 5. Inside the loop, another loop which does a sysout of stars.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681510/regarding-a-star-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop in the range `5 <= n <= 10`, and each time print `"* "` `n` times. At the end of a loop, print a newline.

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 5; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/xl1c1X))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for (int i = 10; i >= 5; i--)
        {
            printStars(i);
        }

    }

    private static void printStars(int i)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 public class Pattern
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int j=10 ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        printStar(j) ;
        System.out.println() ;
        j-- ;

    }




}

static void printStar(int n)
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)

    System.out.print("*") ;     

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using two loops by doing this:

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 5; i--) {
    String stars = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", "* ");
    System.out.println(stars);
}
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * *
```

**Explanation:** What's happening here is a `String` is being created using the specified array of `char`s, which are all initialized to `\0` (the null character). The String at this point contains `i` null characters. The `.replace` is replacing the character sequence `"\0"` with the character sequence `"* "` and the result is a `String` consisting of the repeated sequence.

Comment: Nice answer though. At least easier to remember. But one thing: I dont understand what's going on here: String stars = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", "* ");

Answer (score 0):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution:

```
public static void printPattern(int rows) {
    IntStream.range(0, rows).map(r -> rows - r).forEach(x -> {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, rows + x - 2).forEach(y -> {
            System.out.print(" *");
        });
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
printPattern(6);
```

Output:

```
 * * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * *
 * * * * * *
 * * * * *
```