# How do I create a loop to print the following pattern?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop

I have to create the following pattern by using loop.

```
* * * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
 * * * *
```

Now I can only do that by simply `system.out.print` statement. I don't know how to construct that with a for loop.

My code:

```
    package pattern;

public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("* * * * *");
        System.out.println(" * * * *");
        System.out.println("* * * * *");
        System.out.println(" * * * *");
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try anything with a for loop? Can the pattern be taller or wider? Are there any other requirements?

Comment: I suppose it is an exercise: you have to consider each line alone and each * alone and do something like : for (...) {System.out.print(...);}. Clue: you have to nest two `for`

Comment: What's special about that pattern?

Comment: You've [already posted this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195039/how-to-make-a-loop-to-print-the-following-pattern), and accepted the answer. Sure this pattern is slightly different, but the answer doesn't change much. You won't learn anything by letting people code every line for you. Experiment.

Comment: keyser, but the previous one isn't the same as this one. I have tried to solve this one by my own, but I failed and couldn't figure out the solution. If i see others solution then I might have inspiration and a little further knowledge, which is good for me too.

Comment: "_I have tried to solve this one by my own_" Then why don't you show us that attempt(s)? "_If i see others solution then I might have inspiration_" Or you might just have a copy/paste/turn in assignment situation.

Comment: Obviously like `for(int i=0;i<45;i++)System.out.print(((i>0&&i%9==0)?"\n":"")+((i%2==0)?"*":" "));` : http://ideone.com/MZEPIB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple "**print the checker board question**". You are supposed to use a nested loop to do this:

```
    int row = 5, col = 5;
    for(int x=0; x<row; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<col; y++)
            if ( x % 2 == 0)
                System.out.print("* ");
            else
                System.out.print(" *");     
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

With this kind of question, you should **not** be printing the "*" using `System.out.print ("* * * *")`. Print the repeated `"*"` using loops.

Answer (score 1):

There are a million solutions to this problem, but I would say that when you see a problem, you should first try to break it down into smaller sub-problems that you understand how to solve.

## Part 1: Alternating rows

How can you determine whether or not the row should print `* * * * *` or `* * * *`?  Well, for now assume the existence of a boolean that can tell you which one to print.  Once you have that boolean, the remainder of that problem becomes easy, right?

```
if (shouldPrintFiveStars) {
    System.out.println("* * * * *");
} else {
    System.out.println(" * * * * ");
}
```

## Part 2: Creating your loop

Now, the block that we have above (again, assuming the existence of the `shouldPrintFiveStars` boolean) will correctly print five stars or four stars on a line.  To print multiple lines, we just need to create a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Let's insert the code we did in part 1.
    if (shouldPrintFiveStars) {
        System.out.println("* * * * *");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" * * * * ");
    }
}
```

## Part 3: Finishing up

The code we have thus far should work; we've set it up to alternate rows and to loop through four times.  The only problem?  We've been assuming the existence of this `shouldPrintFiveStars` variable the whole time.  We need to define that in order for this to work.  Once again, there are a number of ways to do this.

The most common approach would probably be to use the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to calculate whether you should print five stars:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // We can replace the condition that we had here previously with modular division.
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("* * * * *");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" * * * * ");
    }
}
```

If you're unfamiliar with modular arithmetic and do not wish to learn it (you really should, it's quite useful), then you can also just do this by toggling a single boolean in each iteration of the loop:

```
// Initialize this to true, since the first row should have five stars; initialize it
// outside the loop, so that its value can be referenced in each subsequent iteration.
boolean shouldPrintFiveStars = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (shouldPrintFiveStars) {
        System.out.println("* * * * *");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" * * * * ");
    }

    // We do this inside the loop, since it needs to change on every iteration.
    shouldPrintFiveStars = !shouldPrintFiveStars;
}
```

Comment: As a note, I think that the questions that [Takendarkk](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3081206/takendarkk) mentioned on the original question are important considerations, even if not explicitly required in your situation.  I intentionally do not answer them here.  You should take it as an exercise upon yourself to understand how to expand a solution like this.  What if there are more columns?  What if it alternates between rows with 4, 5, and 6 stars?  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible working solution with minimal codes:

```
    int size = 5;
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<(size-x%2); y++)
            System.out.print( x % 2 == 0?"* ":" *"); //Inline if        
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

**Program Output:**

```
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

**Explanation:** print `"* "` if row is even number row. Print `" *"` is current row is an odd number row.

Comment: your odd rows are 1 star too long. The pattern in the question alternates between 4 and 5 stars

Comment: @zapl Actually that can easily be solved by amending the y<5 to something else, and I suspect OP himself might actually wants a 5 starts at odd rows too.

Comment: I was just about to suggest to substract the modulo, neat solution :)

Comment: @zapl Thanks, I hope this helps OP, I like my own solution too ;P

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (int i =0; i<10; i++) {
       System.out.println("* * * * *");
       System.out.println(" * * * *"); 
}
```

Comment: We don't know if this exercise is meant to illustrate condition inside itereation or nested iterations. I suggest that you propose an alternative with two nested for as well.

Comment: What do you suggest try and answer what you feel ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     System.out.println("* * * * *");
     System.out.println(" * * * *"); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package pattern;

public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int increment =0; increment<4; increment++) {
            if (increment%2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("* * * * *");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" * * * *");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple logic only try it exactly that pattern

```
class Format1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int r,c;
        for(r=0;r<7;r++)
        {
            for(c=0;c<7;c++){
                if ((r%2==0)&&(c%2==0))
                    System.out.print("*\t");
                else if ((r%2!=0)&&(c%2!=0))
                    System.out.print("*\t");
                else
                    System.out.print("\t");
            }
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```